# How to create a custom base adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter

I'm trying to make my own base adapter to show dynamically RadioButtons in a ListFragment, the code crashes and I don't know exactly what is the cause, but it happens when I try to set the adapter on the ListView.Someone knows what I'm doing wrong?
The XML RadioButton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rbTipo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

The ListView's XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Adapter's Class:

```
public class TipoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<Tipo> tipos;
private Context context;
public TipoAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Tipo> tipos) {
    this.tipos = tipos;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tipos.size();
}

@Override
public Tipo getItem(int i) {
    return tipos.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(view == null){
        view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_tipo_trilha,viewGroup,false);
        holder= new ViewHolder();
        holder.rb=(RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rbTipo);
        view.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    Tipo b = getItem(i);
    holder.rb.setText(b.tipNome);
    holder.rb.setTag(i);

    return view;

}
private static class ViewHolder{
    RadioButton rb;
    public ViewHolder() {
    }
}
```

The ListFragment Class:

```
public class TiposFragment extends ListFragment {
private ArrayList<Tipo> tipos;
private TipoAdapter tipoAdapter;
private int selecionado;
private ListView listView;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
    selecionado = tipoAdapter.getItem(position).tipCod;
    for(int i=0;i<lv.getCount();i++){
        if(i!=position){
         RadioButton rb= (RadioButton)  lv.getChildAt(i);
            rb.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), lv.getChildAt(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tipo_trilha, container, false);
    listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    try {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            tipos = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("tipos");
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (tipos != null) {
        try {
            tipoAdapter = new TipoAdapter(getContext(), tipos);
            listView.setAdapter(tipoAdapter);
            setListAdapter(tipoAdapter);

            // Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(listaTipos.getCount()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("TAG",e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    return view;
}
```

The LogCat Stack Trace:

```
05-09 10:23:03.309 909-909/bdes.dcc.joinville.udesc.br.biketrilhas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: bdes.dcc.joinville.udesc.br.biketrilhas, PID: 909
                                                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to br.udesc.joinville.dcc.bdes.adapter.TipoAdapter$ViewHolder
                                                                                     at br.udesc.joinville.dcc.bdes.adapter.TipoAdapter.getView(TipoAdapter.java:52)
                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2396)
                                                                                     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1290)
                                                                                     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1202)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17834)
                                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:698)
                                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:482)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17834)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5725)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17834)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5725)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17834)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5725)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17834)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5725)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17834)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5725)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17834)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5725)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17834)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5725)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2848)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17834)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2030)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1174)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1395)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1062)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5873)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: Don't say it crashes without posting the stack trace from logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incompatible types in Adapters will lead to crashes. That includes, for instance, trying to display a number inside a TextView on the output of your Adapter, instead of casting it properly using an "Integer.toString(i);".

Answer (score 0):

**1.** In `TiposFragment.java`, replace  all `getContext()` with `getActivity()`.

**2.** Remove below lines from `onCreateView()`:

```
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(tipoAdapter);
```

**Update `TiposFragment` as below:**

```
public class TiposFragment extends ListFragment {
private ArrayList<Tipo> tipos;
private TipoAdapter tipoAdapter;
private int selecionado;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
    selecionado = tipoAdapter.getItem(position).tipCod;
    for(int i=0;i<lv.getCount();i++){
        if(i!=position){
         RadioButton rb= (RadioButton)  lv.getChildAt(i);
            rb.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), lv.getChildAt(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tipo_trilha, container, false);

    try {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            tipos = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("tipos");
        }    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (tipos != null) {
        try {
            tipoAdapter = new TipoAdapter(getActivity(), tipos);
            setListAdapter(tipoAdapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d("TAG",e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    return view;
}
```

Here is a good [tutorial](https://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Using-List-fragment/164465/186980-4.html).

Hope this will help~